# What are these flames on the Falcon 9 booster?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, engines, merlin-1d

When Falcon 9 was on its way to ascend, flames appeared around the bottom of the booster.  What are they?

It seems to begin around about 20:36 in the video, `T+ 00:41` 3.6 km altitude and then appear at more and more locations

[image: video frame grab cropped]

[image: video frame grab]

video cued at `T+ 00:35`:

Comment: Gas Generator exhaust, discussed before:
https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/what-is-that-second-smoke-exhaust-on-a-rocket-engine-for/16751
and
https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31129/what-flame-is-spacexs-hans-koenigsmann-describing-in-his-presentation/31130

Comment: Or combustion gases creeping up the stage and filling the low-pressure area above the engine bells: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/why-are-exhaust-flames-jumping-around-the-bases-of-the-falcon-9-engine-nozzles - I'm leaning towards the latter: the turbopump exhausts are in a ring around the center nozzle, these flames are visible on the  outside of the engines.

Comment: I'd agree with recirculation.

Comment: Related: [Why are exhaust flames “jumping around” the bases of the Falcon-9 engine nozzles; NROL-76?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22305/12102) there's a GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOk6b.gif

Comment: Also related: [What flame is SpaceX's Hans Koenigsmann describing in his presentation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31129/12102)

Answer (score 6):

I think that is [exhaust gas recirculation](https://books.google.nl/books?id=uKihDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT685&lpg=PT685&dq=rocket%20exhaust%20gas%20recirculation&source=bl&ots=p48v18p2hu&sig=UTk4xp6T-smKeegB5goFUYUtp7o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7-4WHrYjfAhVCmbQKHTn-BCg4ChDoATAAegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=rocket%20exhaust%20gas%20recirculation&f=false). Exhaust products [gather in the low-pressure area](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/why-are-exhaust-flames-jumping-around-the-bases-of-the-falcon-9-engine-nozzles) around the base of the rocket.

[image: Diagram showing low-pressure area at base of rocket]

The gas generator exhausts are grouped in a ring around the center engine. I've marked 8 exhausts ([photo source)](https://interestingengineering.com/nside-spacexs-revolutionary-merlin-engine-take-us-mars), nr 9 is not visible here:

[image]

Their flames are long and narrow, and not visible when all engines are running. [In a video of a landing stage](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31129/12102), you can see the gas generator exhaust flame.

Answer (score 3):

That is the exhaust of the gas generator. This is basically an engine that burns the same fuel/oxidizer to turn the turbo pump that makes sure enough fuel/oxidizer gets fed to the engine.

[Smoke Exhaust](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/what-is-that-second-smoke-exhaust-on-a-rocket-engine-for/16751)
[HansK pointing out gas generator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31129/what-flame-is-spacexs-hans-koenigsmann-describing-in-his-presentation/31130)

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that there is a second engine down there.

Comment: See https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22305/12102 as well. btw you may want to link to your answer here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31130/12102 as well.

Comment: In other words, instead of answering by simply linking to your answer, perhaps in this case closing is the correct option. The idea is to point to a good answer rather than re-answer.

Comment: @Alexus There are 9 engines down there. But it is not so much an 'engine' as it is a generator, for the power needed to turn the turbopumps