# How much has fuel efficiency increased in rockets since the Apollo missions?

Tags: rockets, engines, fuel-system, efficiency

I have been talking with a friend of mine and the subject turned to modern rockets versus Apollo era rockets and fuel efficiency.
My friend stated that today’s rockets use half the fuel of the rockets of those days, and can travel equal or further the distance.
This didn’t seem right to me, but I do not understand what factors would go into comparing a rockets fuel efficiency ( He keeps citing better  impulse as the key factor, and a change in fuel types ).

So I would like to know the following:

1. Is this is true that today’s rockets use half the fuel they used to?
2. What metrics would one compare to determine the fuel efficiency and how to compare them?

My apologies if this seems somewhat of a silly question, but after a lot of reading ( tbh a lot of it went over my head ) and googling I could not find a satisfactory answer.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing an "h" in that title. But no, your friend is completely wrong. Efficiency has improved a few percent, not doubled. The second stage of the Saturn V had ISP of 421s, the best test models now can reach 451s(7% better).  What *has* changed is new technologies of propulsion being used, like ion engines etc.

Comment: Ahah yes, I was indeed missing an “ h “. I edited the title thank you. 
 And thank you for your answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can check with your friend that, by twice the fuel-efficiency of a rocket (engine+propellant), he meant "half of the **weight** of fuel" and not necessarily "half of the **same** fuel", which is the fuel efficiceny of the engine alone. It is true that nowadays' rockets do not rely anymore on the Saturn5's 1st stage fuel (see @Robin Bennet's answer), but rather the it's 2nd and 3rd stage's fuel.

Comment: Agree your friend is wrong about the efficiency gain, but also worth noting that you don't need any efficiency gain at all to go the same distance with less fuel - you just have to take a smaller payload (although cutting fuel by half is a stretch).

Comment: Certainly outside of my field here, but as a simple layman, I'd have to imagine that if they're still using the same basic type of fuel, as well as typical rocket propulsion (which goes along with the "every force is met with an equally strong opposite force" rule), they'd have an uphill battle getting past the simple need to burn more fuel to create more force.  Maybe they could focus it better than in earlier spaceships and avoid letting as much of it get effectively wasted, but it seems like the net force would be the main issue, and the energy it needs would be hard to get around.

Comment: It doesn't take that much improvement to get 50% fuel savings, due to the rocket equation exponential.

Comment: @NgPh "nowadays' rockets do not rely anymore on the Saturn5's 1st stage fuel...": er...what? Numerous launchers use the same combination of hydrolox upper stages and kerolox booster as the Saturn V, and several, like the Falcon 9 and Heavy or the Electron, are entirely kerolox. With only a couple exceptions, hydrolox is an upper stage fuel or needs to be combined with strap-on boosters, usually solids.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Even with the same fuel you can have more or less exhaust velocity and therefore ISP. And don’t forget engine design. For example open cycle engines just dump the turbopump exhaust while full-flow staged combustion cycle engines are almost perfect in extracting all energy.

Comment: (@NuclearHoagie) Of course there are also gains to be made by reducing the dry mass that isn't real payload either.  That could result in efficiency savings when looking at the launch system as a whole, but not when looking at the engine

Comment: @Christopher James Huff, indeed! Thanks for correcting. Perhaps if I added "high-end" rockets ... it would be more accurate? Affterthought, as long as fuel is a tiny part of an overall launch cost, there is not much incentive to go for more fuel-efficiency, unless the mission requires so, launching into deep-space, or very heavy payloads for example.

Comment: Change in fuel types? From highly refined kerosene to very highly refined kerosene? ;-)

Comment: Friend is completely wrong, on **every possible level on which one can be wrong**.  Friend is completely wrong in detail, completely wrong conceptually, completely wrong in base understanding of the topic, completely wrong in terminology.

Comment: @NgPh no, that's really not accurate at all. The only two US rockets currently rated to carry crew have kerolox first stages, and one of those is the all-kerolox Falcon 9. The only all-hydrolox US rocket still operating is the Delta IV Heavy, which will soon be retired. ULA's replacement for it uses a methalox first stage, as does Blue Origin's New Glenn. The fully-reusable super-heavy lifter Starship is entirely methalox. Hydrolox first stages are mostly a legacy thing and generally require non-hydrolox boosters.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff, thanks again. "The only wrong is when you don't learn anything from being wrong".

Answer (score 59):

> 1. If this is true that today's rockets use half the fuel they used to?

No.  One might imagine that 60+ years of development must have produced
large gains, but chemical rocket performance is fundamentally limited by
the amount of energy in the chemical fuels, and the 1960s engines were
already getting at least 2/3 of the maximum theoretically possible
performance (see comparison table below).

Now,
[ion thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) technology
has advanced greatly, but those can't be used to reach orbit.

> 2. What metrics would one compare to determine the fuel efficiency and
>    how to compare them?

The usual primary metric is
[specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse).

### Effective exhaust velocity

But specific impulse is a somewhat unintuitive quantity to understand,
so let's start with
[effective exhaust velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse#Specific_impulse_as_effective_exhaust_velocity),
which is the average speed of an exhaust particle (in the backward
direction).  For example, the
[Rocketdyne F-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_F-1) engines
used in the first stage of the
[Saturn V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V) (the Apollo rocket)
have an effective exhaust velocity of 2.58 km/s at sea level.

What does 2.58 km/s mean in terms of rocket performance?  It means if
you build a rocket whose weight is about 63% fuel, and you fire the
engine in deep space until the fuel runs out, the rocket will now be
going 2.58 km/s faster in whatever direction it was pointing:

[image: How v_e translates into delta v]

What if the fuel is not 63% of the weight?  Use the
[Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation):

$$\Delta v = v_e \mathrm{ln} \frac{m_0}{m_f}$$

where $\Delta v$ is how much your velocity changes, $v_e$ is the
effective exhaust velocity, $m_0$ is the initial mass of rocket plus
fuel, and $m_f$ is the final mass of the empty rocket.  I started with
63% $= \left( \frac{e-1}{e} \right)$ because then $\frac{m_0}{m_f}$ is $e$, whose
natural log is 1, meaning $\Delta v = v_e$.

Notice that it doesn't matter how long the burn takes, nor the thrust of
the engine, the final change in velocity is the same.  That's the magic
of the rocket equation!

So, what is change in velocity, $\Delta v$, good for?  In the solar
system there are two main uses for $\Delta v$: launching from the surface
to achieve orbit, and transferring from one orbit to another.  The
article
[Delta-v budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget) has some
examples, but the most relevant to Apollo is the $\Delta v$ to get into
low Earth orbit from a sea level launch, which is (very roughly) around
10 km/s.  That breaks down as about 8 km/s of required velocity to stay
in orbit (any slower and you'll come back down) and 2 km/s spent lifting
the rocket against gravity and pushing through the air on the way up.

The bottom line is, for any given mission, you need a certain amount of
$\Delta v$.  And while you can get more $\Delta v$ by increasing the
proportion of fuel, that gets diminishing returns very quickly due to
the natural log in the rocket equation.  On the other hand, any increase
in $v_e$ translates directly to a proportional increase in $\Delta v$,
which means more mission without sacrificing payload.

### Comparisons

So let's take a quick comparison of $v_e$ for the F-1 and the
[SpaceX Merlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Merlin) engine.
This is a relatively fair comparison because both burn
[RP-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP-1) (refined kerosene) and
liquid oxygen in a
[gas-generator cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-generator_cycle).
These characteristics are good for a first stage due to high energy
density per unit volume and high thrust, although other fuels have
better $v_e$.

```
  F-1              2.58 km/s (sea level)
  Merlin           2.77 km/s (sea level)
  F-1              2.98 km/s (vacuum)     65% of max
  Merlin           3.05 km/s (vacuum)     66% of max
  Theoretical max  4.61 km/s (vacuum)
```

The
[theoretical maximum](https://thephysicsofspacex.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/isp-upper-limits.pdf)
is based on the total chemical energy in the fuel.

I speculate that the better $v_e$ for the Merlin has more to do with its
smaller size, thus making it easier to achieve stable, efficient
combustion, than with technology improvements aimed at performance.

### Specific impulse

Finally then, what is specific impulse?  It's obtained from $v_e$ by
dividing by the gravitational acceleration on Earth:

$$ I_{sp} = \frac{v_e}{g} $$

where $g$ is usually
[standard gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity), or
about $9.81 \frac{m}{s^2}$.  The resulting quantity has units of seconds.  For
example, for the F-1 at sea level, $I_{sp} = 263 s$.

What is the physical significance of $I_{sp}$?  Well, consider our
rocket from before with 63% fuel by mass.  Suppose we start the rocket
while it is sitting on the pad, let it just barely lift off, then hover
just off the pad until it runs out of fuel (this assumes we can
arbitrarily throttle the engine without affecting its performance, which
is not realistic, but ignore that).  $I_{sp}$ is how long it will hover.
That is because, for every second of hovering, we consume 9.81 m/s of
$\Delta v$ in order to overcome gravitational acceleration accumulated
during that second.  After $I_{sp}$ seconds, all of our $\Delta v$ is
gone.

### Fuel types

The question mentioned fuel types.  This answer is already too long,
but I'll just briefly mention that different
[fuel types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_propellant) do have
different performance characteristics, but they also come with other
tradeoffs, and which is best is highly dependent on the mission
objectives.  For example, the Saturn V used RP-1/LOX in its first
stage for high thrust and energy density per volume, but
[LH2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_hydrogen)/LOX in its second
and third stages for better energy density per unit mass and $v_e$,
while the Apollo spacecraft (command/service and lunar modules) used
[hypergolics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergolic_propellant)
for reliability and storability.

Comment: Kudos, this is a great answer!

Comment: Thank you for your well thought out explanation, it really helped me have a better understanding of how specific impulse comes into play.

Comment: Fuel is also extremely complex. There are most likely more dense and more powerful fuel available, but they have really bad tradeoffs like being extremely toxic, creates a lot of toxic byproducts, and so forth, and all these turns into massive $$$ to deal with and process/store/transport, not to mention increased risk of killing people and environmental catastrophe if an accident happens.

Comment: To be complete, thrust does matter greatly when getting off the planet. For one you need a thrust to weight ratio grater than 1, which is where ion drives fail. Higher trust is better because you spend less time fighting gravity; if you want to look it up the term for this is "gravity losses". That said, wikipedia gives typical gravity loss at 2km/s in addition to the 8km/s needed to escape Earth gravity, so with infinite thrust you'd only gain like 20% efficiency.

Comment: @csiz: There's also a tradeoff in terms of needing sturdier rockets to handle higher G loads, increasing the non-fuel part of the rocket mass.  Not to mention payload considerations, especially for crewed flight, of substantially higher accelerations.

Answer (score 54):

> My friend stated that today’s rockets use half the fuel of the rockets of those days, and can travel equal or further the distance.

Your friend doesn't know what they are talking about. That is nonsense. That's not saying it right. It is utter nonsense.

What SpaceX and other new space companies have done is to focus on massively reducing cost rather than slightly improving performance. If reducing cost by a lot means reducing performance by a bit, so be it. If reducing cost by a whole lot means not having a supply chain that involves all 50 states and the District of Columbia, so be it. Old space companies liked those ridiculous supply chains because it made Congress happy. If reducing cost by a whole, whole lot makes Congress a bit less happy, so be it.

What SpaceX has done is to adapt late 20th century / early 21st century concepts to the process of designing, building, and flying rockets. Their engines are no more efficient than were the rockets of the 1960s. Their design and development processes, manufacturing processes, and operational processes are extremely less costly than were those of 1960s era space flight companies.

Comment: Ultimately, SpaceX has taken advantage of the fact that it's not hampered by legacy military/industrial complex rules written by lobbyists and rubber-stamped by Congress.

Comment: Or a bit more provocative, SpaceX is showing why capitalism beats communism in the space race.

Comment: @MSalters: The US had very high income taxes in the Apollo era so it was really a hybrid system (in the best possible way). Public spending on *people* can supply the needed stability and talent to build the *rockets* with private money (or have both public and private space programs to see which does better). Also, technology gets cheaper over time.

Comment: @MSalters given that the actual work done during the space race was performed by private, capitalist, profit-seeking enterprises, I fail to see how you can brand rent-seeking behavior as a "failure of communism". In reality, it is proving that capitalism works phenomenally when paired with gov't capture.

Comment: @MSalters it proves that a coordinated effort for a particular goal is more effective than a committee whose primary motivation is not the completion of the goal.  Given that the soviets put a man in space first with an economy 1/3 the size of the US I don't think Capitalism itself is automatically the winner here.

Comment: @MSalters SpaceX would not be where it is if it wasn't for the large investments NASA made in SpaceX. NASA invested in SpaceX before it had made a single successful flight, continued investing as it showed success, and then invested even more without SpaceX having shown an ability to carry humans into space. SpaceX is not a shining example of capitalism. It is a shining example of a public-private partnership done right.

Comment: @MSalters - I think you compared as a joke the "50 states supply chain" +design by Congress to the "communist" approach which was beaten by XSpace? And most commenters missed the joke?

Comment: @PeterM.-standsforMonica: Correct. I don't think the Soviet Union had worse engineers, nor did it have worse politicians. I just observed that state-run projects are doomed to fail because politicians are not engineers.

Comment: @MSalters Consider the Space Launch System, which is sometimes derogatorily called the Senate Launch System, and is sometimes even more derogatorily called the Shelby Launch System. Politicians are not engineers. The SLS is not the Shelby Cobra of launch vehicles. (That was a different Shelby who made the Shelby Cobra.)

Comment: What has all the cost / politics excursion to do with fuel efficiency?

Comment: @DavidHammen real capitalism is about public-private partnerships

Comment: @user253751, such as today China's "socialism"?

Comment: @Arsenal From NASA's [Artemis I Overview](https://www.nasa.gov/content/artemis-i-overview), "Men and women in all fifty states are hard at work building the Deep Space Exploration Systems to support missions to deep space. NASA prime contractors, Aerojet Rocketdyne, Boeing, Jacobs, Lockheed Martin, and Northrop Grumman currently have over 3,200 suppliers contributing to the milestone achievement that heralds the success of America’s hman[*sic*] spaceflight program."

Comment: @DavidHammen I still don't see the connection to fuel efficiency of rocket engines.

Comment: @Arsenal SpaceX uses fuels that were used in the 1960s or earlier. While they have developed some techniques that makes their rockets a bit more efficient with regard to specific impulse, fuel efficiency is not a prime driver for SpaceX. Cost efficiency is **the** prime driver for SpaceX. Having 3200 suppliers spread across all 50 states is the antithesis of lean manufacturing. Having 3200 suppliers spread across all 50 states is the way to make every senator happy.

Comment: This text does not even attempt to answer the question. Those upvoting it should pause to reflect on the purpose of the voting system. It is not to indicate agreement with an opinion you share.

Comment: @Xerxes It certainly does answer the question, right at the start. The conjecture is utter nonsense.

Comment: @David Hammen, Xerxes is partially right. Although you refuted strongly the quote, you didn't give facts. The OP didn't mention SpaceX at all, just "modern rockets". While you may be very much right in equating "modern rockets business model"=SpaceX, you did'nt show that, in rocket science in general, technically speaking there is no breakthrough in propulsion since Apollo. And that's attempting to address only the 1st question, not the 2nd one.

Answer (score 10):

The [J-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_J-2) engine of the Saturn V 2nd and 3rd stage had two successors, the [J-2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-2X) and the [HG-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HG-3_(rocket_engine)) engines. All three engines used LH2/LOX and were designed for vacuum.

The Shuttle engine [RS-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-25) used the same propellants and there is vacuum data too.

The [RL-10B-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL10) is still used for the Delta III and IV rockets. LH2/LOX is used and there is a specific impulse for vacuum.

So we may compare the specific impulses and the percentage of the theoretical maximum which is 532.5 s for LH2/LOX:

```
type  impulse              dev. start   first flight
J-2   421   s    79.06 %   June  1960   Feb   1966
J-2X  448   s    84.13 %   July  2007
HG-3  451   s    84.69 %
RS-25 452.3 s    84.94 %   about 1970   April 1981
RL-10 465.5 s    87.42 %                      1998
```

So there is an improvement. But the HG-3 was cancelled and never flew.

Comment: The RS-25 doesn't really fit in this comparison, because it didn't have a truely vacuum-optimised nozzle, else it would beat the others by quite a bit thanks to its staged combustion cycle.

Answer (score 10):

David Hammen's answer is right, but I would also add that none of *today's* rockets have the payload capacity of the Saturn V. That's why they use half the fuel, because they are not launching humans to the moon.(With all the support equipment that requires.) Starship Heavy and New Glen are *tomorrow's* rockets, and they are every bit as large or larger as Saturn V. And they will use even more fuel than Apollo did. But by reusing the booster and other parts, as well as other efficiencies, they can substantially reduce price.

Comment: The OP talked about a particular performance index: fuel efficiency (specific impulse) think you are mixing in a number performance indexes: thrust and cost. This is akin to comparing cars using weight capacity and/or cost when the subject of discussion is mileage.

Comment: @NgPh OP never said "specific impulse" OP said, "half the fuel...[to go]...equal or further the distance." That demonstrates total naiveté with regard to the costs of space exploration. Nobody who knows what they're talking about ever asks how many miles per gallon a launch system gets. Brianorca's answer (somewhat) and David Hammen's answer (moreso) talk about the _important_ costs.

Comment: @Solomon Slow, the OP also expressed the following: "I do not understand what factors would go into comparing a rockets fuel efficiency (He keeps citing better impulse as the key factor, and a change in fuel types )". I don't understand your "absolute naiveté" nor David Hammen's "utter nonsense". There are many other ways to enlighten someone that progress in business efficiency is more prominent than in fuel efficiency. Besides, the OP didn't claim that the OP cited friend faithfully. And IMO there is nothing wrong about asking questions on subjects you do not master.

Answer (score 5):

Specific impulse is indeed the main way that rocket engine efficiency is compared, as a rocket has to lift its own fuel.

There's a table on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse#Examples), but it also includes lots of non-rocket engines, and doesn't include any SpaceX engines. So here's a few I've collected for you:

[Saturn5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V) 1st stage: 263s
Saturn5 2nd and 3rd stage: 421s
[Space Shuttle RS-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse#Examples): 453s
[Raptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor): 365–380s

Higher numbers are better, so no, it hasn't improved much.

Comment: You should not compare apples with oranges. Saturn V 1st stage engine was using RP1/LOX, the 2nd and 3rd stage engine used LH2/LOX. The Shuttle engine used LH2/LOX too. The raptor engine uses LCH4/LOX. You can't tell from this numbers if there was an improvement at all for the Raptor. The Shuttle engine was an improvement compared with Saturn V 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to compare payload weight vs. overall weight? Or payload vs. fuel weight?

Comment: Also, the RS-25 was 453s **in vacuum**.  At launch on the pad its ISP is only 366s and it's paired there with solid boosters making 60% of the vehicle launch thrust at only 242s ISP.

Comment: Saturn V 1st stage specific impulse is given for sea level, 2nd and 3rd stage engines for vacuum.

Comment: @Uwe the question was whether fuel efficiency in rockets has increased overall since Apollo, not whether it improved for RP1 specifically(it has btw, the RD180 gets 310s). If SpaceX has mastered using a better fuel and can get 360+s in Raptor, that counts. And going from 260s->360s. That's a 39% improvement, which is very solid. For reference, commercial jet engines improved their efficiency by 45% over the same period: https://theicct.org/publications/fuel-efficiency-trends-new-commercial-jet-aircraft-1960-2014

Comment: @Eugene NASA has mastered using a better fuel for the Saturn V 2nd and 3rd stage than for the 1st, 421 s is much better than 263 s. SpaceX has mastered to use a worse fuel for Raptor, 365-380 s is worse than 421 s. LCH4/LOX is not a better fuel than LH2/LOX. The theoretical maximum specific impulse of LCH4/LOX is 458,7 s, for LH2/LOX it is 532.5 s. The Saturn V 2nd stage engine achieved 79.07 % of the theoretical maximum, the Raptor 79.57 %. The 1st stage of Saturn V achieved only 55.93 % at sea level, not at vacuum.

Comment: @Uwe Correct, but the first stage is the lion's share of the weight and cost of a rocket, and hydrogen is so light that the tank weight is prohibitive(especially with the added insulation due to the ultra-cryo temperature), so with the exception of the Delta 4, everyone used RP1 or solid. A ~40% ISP improvement with a fuel that only needs ~14% more overall tank volume than RP1 and is therefore well-suited for the part of the rocket that matters the most, is solid progress.

Comment: The Raptor numbers are for the vacuum version of the engine. The Raptor engines used for launch have a specific impulse of 330 seconds.

Comment: @DavidHammen my bad, should have checked which numbers the answer was using, but when I did, I discovered that even the wiki article has 2 different numbers for sea level ISP(330s/350s) in different parts of the article, with different sources. It looks like the 330s is for the 1st version that flew on SN8-SN10 and 350s is for the later iterations of Raptor 1 or Raptor 2.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Is this is true that today’s rockets use half the fuel they used to?

No, but cars, trucks trains and airplanes do.  And for everyone but those on the rocket, that's a much bigger net gain, because we use all those a heck of a lot more than we use rockets.

The simple fact is there isn't a lot of gain *to be made* in rockets. It's like if you have a common "80%" gas furnace, you're not going to double its fuel efficiency.  Besides, **inefficiency causes heat**, and that heat would need to be ejected somehow, or else equipment will overheat.  **On a rocket in space, there is nowhere for heat to go** except out the nozzle *(or other exhaust pipe)*.

On that point, there is one notable gain in *how they power the fuel and oxidizer pumps*. Historically, the pumps were powered by a *[gas generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-generator_cycle)* which consumed fuel and oxidizer, and threw its hot exhaust overboard.  Even worse, stochiometric (perfect ratio) combustion would make the turbine too hot, so they add considerable mass of extra fuel just to cool the airstream down!  All utterly wasted - a) lost heat energy, b) loss of reaction mass since rockets work by ejecting mass (their exhaust) at very high velocity, and c) loss of fuel value from that "cooling" fuel.

[image]

*Rolling coal: The black smoke is the very rich "gas generator" exhaust*. [source](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/what-is-that-second-smoke-exhaust-on-a-rocket-engine-for)

Meanwhile, cold/liquified fuel and oxidizer need to be turn from liquid to vapor in order to burn in the engine. This *latent heat of vaporization* was "stolen" from engine thrust.  (fuel is pre-heated in the engine nozzle jacket, but nothing pre-heated oxidizer.)

This isn't anywhere near 50%, but it's the biggest opportunity for efficiency gains available.

Today, the *[staged combustion cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staged_combustion_cycle)* has been mainstreamed.  This is where some fuel is combined with all the oxidizer (or vice versa), used to power the turbo pump, and fed into the main rocket engine.  Thus the formerly discarded exhaust heat is providing some latent heat of vaporization to the oxidizer (fuel).

The trade-off is you need much better metallurgy tech in the turbine metals (that's why gas generators used excess fuel instead of oxidizer; the latter is much more corrosive). But the pump seals do not need to be perfect - small internal leaks along the rotating shaft between the raw oxidizer pump and the oxidizer-rich turbine cause no trouble at all except for a microscopic loss of pump efficiency.

However it still needs a perfect seal between oxidizer and fuel!  SpaceX gets rid of that, with *a complete second set of burners and turbines* that run *fuel-rich*, and use that to pump the fuel. Again, minor leaks between fuel-rich exhaust and raw fuel are no great concern.

So to answer your question, going to staged combustion has been an efficiency bump for rocket engines, yes - though certainly not anything like 50%.

> and a change in fuel types

Energy per mass of fuel *[is not the same](http://www.braeunig.us/space/propel.htm)* from fuel to fuel.

Indeed, liquid hydrogen is "top of the heap". But you don't see a lot of designs using it. That's because it's fairly difficult to work with, so they willingly pay the efficiency cost to use a more manageable fuel like RP-1 (kerosene).

Comment: " an obscure Soviet technology" The 1970s era Space Shuttle Main Engine was a staged combustion engine. Maybe you're really talking about O2 rich staged combustion? Or full flow staged combustion?  The SSME was neither of those.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Good point, removed.